# Random Vectors Regardless of Order

Tags: r, random, vector

What I am looking to do is generate n vectors of length k such that each value in the vector is a random number, and that there are no repeated vectors regardless of order of the integers in each vector. For example, there would not be both the vectors 1,2,3 and 2,1,3.

So far what I have is the following to generate one vector, and I was planning on looping through this code to generate the n vectors.

```
vector<- sample(1:20000,k)
```

One idea that I had would be to sort all vectors in ascending order and then remove duplicate vectors. Is there an easier/more efficient way?

Thanks!

Comment: Minor question: how big will `k` be? (There may be performance implications.)

Comment: Large. On the order of 10 000 or greater

Comment: I think your plan is good.

Answer (score -1):

One approach would be to generate all the possible combinations, then choose from that set.  This would guarantee no duplicates:

```
> tmp <- combn(100, 3)
> dim(tmp)
[1]      3 161700
> tmp[ , sample( ncol(tmp), 10 ) ]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   34   35   28    3    3   29    8   24   50    53
[2,]   54   54   63   57   17   86   31   30   52    81
[3,]   97   79   87   92   53   94   90   83   87    97
```

Of course this will only work if the total number of combinations can fit in memory.  Though there are ways to iterate through the combinations and only keep some, or to generate a sample of integers, then convert them to the appropriate combination.

If the number of samples you want is small relative to the number of possible combinations then the rejection method will probably be more efficient.  But this could work better if the number of samples is large relative to the number of combinations which would lead to a large number of duplicates.

Comment: The number of samples is relatively small: for example, 100, and the number of combinations is large (number of ways of sampling 100 from 20 000). I would then also want to vary the number of samples from 1 to 100 so this could be challenging.